# Create Public Document without login for readonly permissions

Tags: authentication, readonly, doc

I want to create a doc file which is accessible to every one without login to any website(google etc). Only read only permission is there .

Answer (score 0):

you can upload into dropbox public folder and then share link to whom you want to share.

After uploading to dropbox, right click on the you have uploaded and then select

```
Dropbox->Share link
```